# Android: How to show/skip the Splash Screen as needed when opening an app through a notification?

Tags: android

*(Note: My app's targetSdk and compileSdk are set to 29, so I can't take advantage of the new SplashScreen API)*

I have a very simple app with two activities:

1. **SplashActivity** - Default activity opened with the launcher icon. Shows a splash screen, loads some stuff, and when complete, calls `startActivity()` to start the Main Activity and then calls `finish()` to finish itself.
2. **Main Activity** - It just posts a notification. When pressing that notification, the app should be brought to the foreground.

What do I mean by "the app should be brought to the foreground"? To be clear:

1. If `MainActivity` already exists (either in the background or foreground), open that same instance.
2. If `MainActivity` was destroyed (the user previously pressed Back), then open the `SplashActivity`. The splash activity will redirect you itself to `MainActivity`.

In fact, **this is exactly the default behavior of the launcher icon**.

However, I can't get my app to behave this way when the notification is pressed. Either it's always opening the `SplashScreen`, or it's always opening the `MainActivity` directly and skipping the Splash Screen.

Ideally, I would like to do this:

```java
Intent intent;
if (MainActivity already exists) {
  // Bring that instance of MainActivity to the foreground
  intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
} else {
  // No UI activity exists for the app. Start from the Splash Screen.
  intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
}
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
...
// later
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

But I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be checking for the existence of `MainActivity` myself. I should be using a combination of Intent Flags and activity launch modes.

Answer (score 2):

in the manifest you should add the following to your main activity

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

then my notification looks as follows

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(text));

mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

Intent goToAppIntent = context.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName())
                .setPackage(null)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

PendingIntent piGoToApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, goToAppIntent, 0);
mBuilder.addAction(0,"go to app",piGoToApp);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(piGoToApp);
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: It works by doing `goToAppIntent.setPackage(null)` (everything else wasn't needed). I'm surprised. Do you know why ?

Comment: I can tell you that if you dont set launchmode to singleTask you will get an issue but only sometimes (its weird but I had this issue recently). I think by setting package to null it implicitly tries to find whatever activity is currently running under your packagename once you feed it to getActivity

Comment: And you are completely right, I pretty mich just copy pasted my own notification code and not all the settings i used will be relevant to you. I can tell you though that building your intent using the package manager is pretty neat as it will take you back to your current activity whichever that is. so you can get rid of that if statement of yours that is bound to grow once you add more activities ;)

Comment: I created this repo: https://github.com/HectorRicardo/getLaunchIntent-bug . Would you mind taking a look at it? It talks about the fact that `goToAppIntent.setPackage(null)` is needed, which I believe it's an Android bug.

Comment: not sure if its a bug. you could consider it a feature. read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setPackage(java.lang.String).  I think what your code didnt do is take care of referencing the same instance of the activity that you want to go to. using setPackage(null) does exactly this. it returns the same instance of the activity that already exists

Comment: Que tal hermano, look this is the docu on getlaunchIntent https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String) . as you can see it says that it returns "intent to launch a front-door activity in a package" thats why in your case it returns the SplashScreen cause thats your front door i.e. Launcher activity. thats what its supposed to do.

Comment: "Using setPackage(null) does exactly this. it returns the same instance of the activity that already exists". Exactly where in the documentation does it say that "it returns the same instance of the activity that already exists"? In fact, the docs say that "If left to the default value of null, all components in all applications will considered".

Comment: Also, why wouldn't getLaunchIntent behave the same as the intent from the launcher icon? I mean, if the app is minimized, and you press the launcher icon from Home, it skips the Splash Screen (even though the intent points to the Splash screen). Why wouldn't getLaunchIntent do that? After all, it's named getLaunchIntent

Comment: I mean you are right in pointing out that the documentation is not stellar, in fact there are even some gramatical issues in there. And yes it never says explicitly that setting package(null) will return the current instance of the currently active activity in your app. I just would call this poorly written/confusing documentation (of which this for sure isnt the only instance) and not necessarily a bug. As for your second comment I think the documentation is trying to say that it will return the launcher intent of your app as if it wasnt open and not the intent executed when clicking the icon

Comment: but this is just my interpretation based on the facts on the ground. I am totally with you in saying that the documentation is really poor when it comes to such an essencial functionallity as going back to your app from a notification.